# How to find folders that contain files with a given extension

Tags: vb.net, directory-structure

I am a novice and have seen that System.IO may provide what I need but I can't work out how. I'm using **VB.net**

Starting at a given folder e.g. **C:\StartHere** I want to recurse down the folder hierarchy looking for any folders that contain files with a given extension e.g. ***.exe**. I want to build a list of those folders for subsequent processing.

I would be very grateful if someone could give help as I don't know the best way to approach this.

**UPDATE**

The following provides more details as requested by Andrew Morton.
Starting from a specified folder, I want to get a list containing the full paths to all sub-folders that contain EXEs. So presented with the following folders…

```
C:\StartHere\folderA (contains some EXEs)
C:\StartHere\folderB (none in here)
C:\StartHere\Deeper\DeepC (contains some EXEs)
C:\StartHere\Deeper\DeepD (contains some EXEs)
C:\StartHere\Deeper\DeepE (none in here)
C:\StartHere\Deeper\DeepF (contains some EXEs)
```

The code would result in a list containing:

```
C:\StartHere\folderA 
C:\StartHere\Deeper\DeepC
C:\StartHere\Deeper\DeepD
C:\StartHere\Deeper\DeepF
```

The code that I now have follow the great help from @Tim Schmelter, @Jimi and @Andrew Morton is this:

```
Dim folderList = Directory.EnumerateDirectories("C:\StartHere", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(Function(d) Directory.EnumerateFiles(d, "*.exe").Any()).Select(Function(f) Path.GetDirectoryName(f))
```

When run, it creates the following list; so it has found the right folders but is adding their parent folder to the list rather than the full path:

```
C:\StartHere 
C:\StartHere\Deeper
C:\StartHere\Deeper
C:\StartHere\Deeper
```

Comment: Remove `.Select(Function(f) Path.GetDirectoryName(f))` part.

Comment: You are showing the code from Andrew from [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68519235/how-to-find-folders-that-contain-files-with-a-given-extension/68519326?noredirect=1#comment121094608_68519326) to my question. It makes sense that it always returns the parent-dir from the desired directory because he uses `Path.GetDirectoryName(f)` on the initally projected directory(so `f` is not the file but the directory). My code is different, i select the child-directory in my 2nd LINQ query, so it didn't work? But you can also use Andrew's code, replace the last part with `Select dir`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's [a method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-5.0) which does already what you need:

```
Dim exeList = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\StartHere", "*.exe", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList()
```

Edit: I misunderstood the question first, so you want a list of all folders that contain at least one exe file? You could use this LINQ query:

```
Dim exeDirs = From dir In IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories("C:\StartHere", "*.*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
              Where IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir).Any(Function(file) IO.Path.GetExtension(file).Equals(".exe", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
Dim exeDirList As List(Of String) = exeDirs.ToList()
```

Comment: Hi Tim and many thanks. I have tried that and it works but exeList appears to contain a list of EXE files rather than the folders. How can I just get the folders?

Comment: @MaxHeadroom: Edited the answer. It needs `Imports System.Linq`

Comment: There's a typo in EnumerateDirectories (missing pattern `"*"`) and `select dir` has been probably cut out.

Comment: You have `SearchOption.AllDirectories` in there. Select is not needed in query mode?

Comment: @Jimi: sorry you're right with the pattern, needs that overload because of the `SearchOption`. But the `Select` is optional. Edited my answer. I was just testing if it compiles in LinqPad, don't know why it did.

Comment: @Jimi: No, in VB.NET is the `Select` in query mode optional. If you omit it you will select what's in the `From`. You could even have multiple `From`, then you'll select an anonymous type containing those.

Comment: Well, I usually *translate* C# code to VB.Net, so I never noticed. It's actually *implicit* here. I prefer the *explicit* version (in case someone *translates* the code in the opposite direction), but good to know.

Comment: Thanks again to both Tim and Jimi. I still can't get it to work.

Comment: @MaxHeadroom Is the code giving an error, or the wrong results?

Comment: Hi Andrew, running in debug and inspecting exeDirList it shows a count of zero, so it's not populating the list correctly

Comment: @MaxHeadroom Tim can adjust his answer from this: `Dim hasExe = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(startHere, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(Function(d) Directory.EnumerateFiles(d, "*.exe").Any()).Select(Function(f) Path.GetDirectoryName(f))`. It needs just `"*"` to search the directories, and using `"*.exe"` as the filter for `Directory.EnumerateFiles` makes it case-insensitive. (If you're working on an OS other than Windows, that latter might not apply.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes, that looks fine. But it should give the same result.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ah, yes, I don't know why I didn't compare the results from your code to my attempt earlier. Maybe the tree the OP is looking in has no .exe files.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I failed to appreciate what Tim was advising me to do - Doh!  This now works but the list items contain the path of the parent rather than the full path of the child folder. Just to be clear. If folder "C:\FolderA" contains 3 sub-folders called Sub1, Sub2, Sub3 what the list contains is 3 items all containing "C:\FolderA"

Comment: I have updated the original question to provide more detail and show where the code from Tim is nearly there but not quite. Any help would be mightily appreciated

Comment: @MaxHeadroom: Either use my code(you're using Andrews) - it should work in my opinion - or use Andrews but omit the `Select` because `Path.GetDirectoryName(f)` returns the parent from f(which is the directory not file).

Comment: Tim you are a saint. I reverted to your code and it works - many thanks.